# Generate List of random Floats in a sequence for Mocking IoT Sensor

Tags: python, random, iot

I have been struggling to mock the IoT Sensor data. I need a list of floats which will increase and decrease sequentially.
For example [0.1, 0.12, 0.13, 0.18, 1.0, 1.2, 1.0, 0.9, 0.6]
Right now I have generated the list with max and min range using this,

```
for k in dts:
    x = round(random.uniform(j["min"], j["max"]), 3)
    random_float_list.append(x)
```

list generated form this code is not in a sequence. I need something which generates random floats in range and there are no abrupt changes in it. Values can increase and decrease in a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate random numbers with a uniform distribution, and then sort the numbers into ascending order in the first part, and into descending order in the second part.

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)


def gen_rnd_sensor_data(low: float,
                        high: float,
                        n_incr: int,
                        n_decr: int) -> np.ndarray:
    incr = np.random.uniform(low=low, high=high, size=n_incr)
    incr.sort()
    decr = np.random.uniform(low=low, high=high, size=n_decr)
    decr[::-1].sort()
    return np.concatenate((incr, decr))
```

Then you can call this function with:

```py
print(gen_rnd_sensor_data(0, 1, 5, 3))
```

This generates data within 0. and 1., the first 5 values are increasing, the last 3 are decreasing. Within the program, every time you call the function, you get different results, but if you rerun your program, you get the same results, so you can debug your program.

Comment: If you want the **differences** to be uniformly distributed (instead of the values themselves), then generating n_incr number of random numbers using a uniform distribution, then calculating the cumulative sum can solve this type of feature request too.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate multiple random sequences and glue them together. Something like this:

```
import numpy as np


def gen_floats(count, min_step_size, max_step_size, max_seq_len):
    # Start around 0
    res = [np.round(np.random.rand() - 0.5, 2)]
    while len(res) < count:
        step_size = np.random.uniform(min_step_size, max_step_size)
        # Generate random number of steps for sequence
        remaining = count - len(res)
        steps = np.random.randint(1, remaining + 1 if remaining < max_seq_len else max_seq_len)
        # Generate additive or subtractive sequence using previous values
        if np.random.rand() > 0.5:
            vals = np.round(np.linspace(res[-1] + step_size, res[-1] + steps * step_size, steps), 2)
        else:
            vals = np.round(np.linspace(res[-1] + step_size, res[-1] - steps * step_size, steps), 2)
        res.extend(vals)
    return res
```

Then `print(gen_floats(20, 0.1, 0.5, 10))` generates something like: `[0.4, 0.86, 0.25, -0.37, -0.99, -1.61, -2.23, -2.85, -2.64, -2.95, -3.26, -3.57, -3.88, -3.63, -3.38, -3.19, -2.89, -2.63, -3.15, -3.68]`. You can play with params to match desired output.

Comment: what if we want to give a min max range?

Comment: you can limit the values using `np.clip` ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work if you want a random where you can control the min, max and max difference between the values.

It will first random a value between `start` and `end` and append it to the list `output`. The next value will be a random value between the last value in the `output` list `+-max_diff`.

```
import random
def rand(start,end,max_diff,elements,output):
    elements -= 1
    if output:
        if output[-1]-max_diff < start: #To not get a value smaller than start
            output.append(round(random.uniform(start,output[-1]+max_diff),3))
        elif output[-1]+max_diff > end: #To not get a value bigger than end
            output.append(round(random.uniform(output[-1]-max_diff,end),3))
        else:
            output.append(round(random.uniform(output[-1]-max_diff,output[-1]+max_diff),3))
    else:
        output.append(round(random.uniform(start,end),3))
    if elements > 0:
        output = rand(start,end,max_diff,elements,output)
    return output

print(rand(1,2,0.1,3,[])) #[1.381, 1.375, 1.373]
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use the following code to generate dummy continuous sensor data and plot in graph:

```
%matplotlib notebook

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal 

#Set configutations
ORDER_COUNT = 3
MAX_BUFFER_SZ = 1000
FRAME_SZ = 200

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ORDER_COUNT, 1, figsize=(8, ORDER_COUNT*3))

lines = []
all_lines = []
data_buffer = []

for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    line, = ax.plot([], [])
    lines.append(line)
    ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
    ax.set_ylim(-3, 3)
    ax.set_xlabel('Time')
    ax.set_ylabel('Graph no: ' + str(i))

def update(frame):
    new_data = np.random.randn(1)
    data_buffer.append(new_data)
    if len(data_buffer) > MAX_BUFFER_SZ:
        data_buffer.pop(0)
    x_data = np.arange(len(data_buffer))
    for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
        lines[i].set_data(x_data, np.array(data_buffer))
        ax.set_xlim(max(0, len(data_buffer) - FRAME_SZ), len(data_buffer))
        all_lines.append(lines[i])
    return all_lines

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=FRAME_SZ, blit=True, interval=1)
plt.show()
```